# Using android SQLite table not found "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:"

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem about using SQLite database in an android project. I added my DB in assets folder. I try to access any table on DB but application gives an error with my HTC Desire S device "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:". Can you give me any advise about it?

My code:

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Airports";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_CODE = "Code";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String COLUMN_NAMEFORSEARCH = "NameForSearch";
public static final String COLUMN_SEQUENCE = "OrderIndex";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.pordiva.cepyol.activities/databases/";
private static String DB_NAME = "cepyol.db";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 * 
 * @param context
 */
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cepyol";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public FlightSQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}


/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    myDataBase = null;

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path

        myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
        myDataBase.close();
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {


    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public static String getDatabaseName() {
    return DATABASE_NAME;
}

public static int getDatabaseVersion() {
    return DATABASE_VERSION;
}
```

Calling there:

```
private int[] checkDB() {
    FlightSQLiteHelper myDbHelper = new FlightSQLiteHelper(this);

    int[] value = null;

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.query("Airports", new String[] { "_id" }, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int index = 0;
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                value[index] = c.getInt(index);
                index++;
            }

        }

        myDbHelper.close();

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {

        throw sqle;

    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: you are supposed to create the table in public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase) { ..

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to create the table in public void onCreate(..

```
// Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
            + " text not null);";//<-- change it as per you need

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase) {
 database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```